# Azure get_blob only return 4KB of image size

Tags: python, azure

I am using the code below to download the image from blob storage, but it only download 4KB of the 10MB picture:

```
  file = blob.get_blob('picture', filename)
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(file)
```

Anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Are you writing your own code top of REST API? and if yes would you please share full code? It seems to me that the call is only return the headers first however you would need to specific the total pages in your subsequent headers to download all the pages from the blob.

Comment: No I am using the python SDK provided by Microsoft Azure.

Comment: I am using the sample from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/how-to-guides/blob-service/#download-blobs

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
        // Retrieve the content of a blob. 
    // Return true on success, false if not found, throw exception on error.

    public string GetBlob(string container, string blob)
    {
        return Retry<string>(delegate()
        {
            HttpWebResponse response;

            string content = null;

            try
            {
                response = CreateRESTRequest("GET", container + "/" + blob).GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                response.Close();
                return content;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError &&
                    ex.Response != null &&
                    (int)(ex.Response as HttpWebResponse).StatusCode == 409)
                    return null;

                throw;
            }
        });
    }
```